# node - make a request retry on 429 error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request

I am using the node module 'request' to send up some JSON to my REST API.

I have the following call

```
request({
    uri: urlToUse, // Using the url constructed above.
    method: "POST", // POSTing to the URI
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonItems),
    headers: // Allows us to authenticate. 
    {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 
        'Authorization' : auth 
    }},
    //What to do after the request...
    function(err, response, body)
    {
        // Was there an error?
        if (err)
        {
            // If so, log it.
            console.log(err);
        }
        // Did the server respond?
        if (response)
        {
            // Log it.
            console.log(response.statusCode);

            // Did the response have a body?
            if(body)
            {
                // Log it.
                console.log(body);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to add to this - I would like to be able to act on a 429 status code - in order to make it retry the request until complete.

I know how to detect the 429 (using an if statement to check response.statusCode, etc), But I don't know how to make it retry, or if that is even the way to do it best.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request I assume this is the module you are using then?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see anything about retries. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you want to do is just wrap all this code in a function and then have it call itself if the response code is 429. perhaps even include a "try attempt" number as the last optional parameter to this function, you can then keep a count of how many times you've called it, and act accordingly to your preference